# Have Fuzzy Lookup in Excel list matched table vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: excel, powerquery, fuzzy-search

By default, Fuzzy Lookup spits out it's matches side by side, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to configure Fuzzy Lookup so that in the above example, there would just be 2 columns, Source and Similarity, such that the table would look like:

[image]

Or perhaps there's a way this can be done easily with Power Query?

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Similarity column in PQ and use "Unpivot Other Columns".